# Unassigned outputs in VHDL simulation

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I've been having problems while simulating a code in VHDL in ModelSim, the purpose of the code was to make a sum and a subtraction of two numbers, represented as vectors and store the results in two another vectors. But, when I start the simulation, the output vectors stay with the value 'U', of unassigned. This code was made by my professor, so I believe that there are no mistakes in it, but I do not know how to make the outputs give the results I want. The code and its testbench are here:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity addsub is
    port (
        \a\ : out   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        \s\ : out   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        \x\ : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        \y\ : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
end addsub;

architecture behavior of addsub is

component add_op_s
generic (
    w_in1   : integer := 8;
    w_in2   : integer := 8;
    w_out   : integer := 16
);
port (
    I0  : in    std_logic_vector(w_in1-1 downto 0);
    I1  : in    std_logic_vector(w_in2-1 downto 0);
    O0  : out   std_logic_vector(w_out-1 downto 0)
);
end component;

component sub_op_s
generic (
    w_in1   : integer := 16;
    w_in2   : integer := 16;
    w_out   : integer := 32
);
port (
    I0  : in    std_logic_vector(w_in1-1 downto 0);
    I1  : in    std_logic_vector(w_in2-1 downto 0);
    O0  : out   std_logic_vector(w_out-1 downto 0)
);
end component;

signal s5   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal s3   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal s4   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal s2   : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin

    \x_sub_op_s_y\: sub_op_s
    generic map (
        w_in1 => 32,
        w_in2 => 32,
        w_out => 32
    )
    port map (
        I0 => s3,
        I1 => s4,
        O0 => s5
    );

    \x_add_op_s_y\: add_op_s
    generic map (
        w_in1 => 32,
        w_in2 => 32,
        w_out => 32
    )
    port map (
        I0 => s3,
        I1 => s4,
        O0 => s2
    );

    s3 <= \x\;
    s4 <= \y\;
    \a\ <= s2;
    \s\ <= s5;

end behavior;
```

Testbench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity t_addsub is
end t_addsub;

architecture behavior of t_addsub is

component addsub
port (
    \a\ : out   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    \s\ : out   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    \x\ : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    \y\ : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end component;

signal \a\  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal \s\  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal \x\  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal \y\  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

uut: addsub
port map (
    \a\ => \a\,
    \s\ => \s\,
    \x\ => \x\,
    \y\ => \y\
);

x_atribution: process
begin

    wait for 10 ns;

    wait for 10 ns;
    \x\ <= conv_std_logic_vector(1,32);
    wait for 10 ns;
    \x\ <= conv_std_logic_vector(2,32);
    wait for 10 ns;
    \x\ <= conv_std_logic_vector(3,32);
    wait for 10 ns;
    \x\ <= conv_std_logic_vector('X', 32);
wait;
end process x_atribution;

y_atribution: process
begin

    wait for 10 ns;

    wait for 10 ns;
    \y\ <= conv_std_logic_vector(3,32);
    wait for 10 ns;
    \y\ <= conv_std_logic_vector(2,32);
    wait for 10 ns;
    \y\ <= conv_std_logic_vector(1,32);
    wait for 10 ns;
    \y\ <= conv_std_logic_vector('X', 32);
wait;
end process y_atribution;

process

begin

    wait for 10 ns;

    wait on \s\;
    assert \a\ = conv_std_logic_vector(4,32)
        report "value different from the expected" severity error;

    assert false report "end of test of \a\" severity note;

wait;
end process;

process

begin

    wait for 10 ns;

    wait on \s\;
    assert \s\ = conv_std_logic_vector(-2,32)
        report "value different from the expected" severity error;

    wait on \s\;
    assert \s\ = conv_std_logic_vector(0,32)
        report "value different from the expected" severity error;

    wait on \s\;
    assert \s\ = conv_std_logic_vector(2,32)
        report "value different from the expected" severity error;

    assert false report "end of test of \s\" severity note;

wait;
end process;

process

begin

    wait for 10 ns;

    wait on \a\;
    assert \a\ = conv_std_logic_vector(4,32)
        report "value different from the expected" severity error;

    wait for 12 ns;
    assert \a\ = conv_std_logic_vector(4,32)
        report "value different from the expected" severity error;

    wait for 10 ns;
    assert \a\ = conv_std_logic_vector(4,32)
        report "value different from the expected" severity error;

    assert false report "end of test of \a\" severity note;

wait;
end process;

process

begin

    wait for 10 ns;

    wait on \s\;
    assert \s\ = conv_std_logic_vector(-2,32)
        report "value different from the expected" severity error;

    wait for 12 ns;
    assert \s\ = conv_std_logic_vector(0,32)
        report "value different from the expected" severity error;

    wait for 10 ns;
    assert \s\ = conv_std_logic_vector(2,32)
        report "value different from the expected" severity error;

    assert false report "end of test of \s\" severity note;

wait;
end process;

end behavior;
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a moment reading in [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), since that will give you a better answer rate and experience when using this forum.

Comment: The `add_op_s` and `sub_op_s` are not provided, so if these are neither included in your simulation, it won't work.  For debugging of code like this, try to reduce the design until it gets so simple that you can spot the bug; that will learn you to do debugging.